# C++11 function wrapper type depending on wrappee return type

Tags: c++11, metaprogramming

I am wrapping some C legacy functions with C++ wrapper classes. I would like to do the following:

```
template<typename Function>
class NonVoidWrapper {
private:
    Function func_;
public:
    NonVoidWrapper(Function func) : func(func_) {}
    template <typename... Args>
    auto operator()(Args&&... args) -> decltype(func_(std::forward<Args>(args)...))
    {
       return func_(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    }
};

template<typename Function>
class VoidWrapper {
private:
    Function func_;
public:
    VoidWrapper(Function func) : func(func_) {}
    template <typename... Args>
    void operator()(Args&&... args)
    { 
        func_(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    }
};
```

Then the function makeWrapper would return a wrapper object based on the function return type like the following:

```
template<typename R, typename... Args>
struct ReturnType {
    typedef R type;
};

template <typename Func>
auto makeWrap(Func f)
{
    return std::conditional<std::is_void<typename ReturnType<decltype(f)>::type>::value, VoidWrapper<Func>, NonVoidWrapper<Func> >::type(f);
}
```

The problem is that the code above doesn't compile, because the return type depends on the template parameters. I know this is weird and might not work in case the function is overloaded, but nevertheless this has to be done :)

### Note

I really need to use two different wrappers as shown above, as they do slightly different things inside

### Q2

Solution suggested by T.C. works, however how can one also encompass lambda functions (that need to capture arguments but accept and return void for example)?

A2:

I did **Q2** like this, it only works for lambdas that return void though

```
template<typename F>
struct FuncReturnType {
    typedef void type;
};

template<typename R, typename... Args>
struct FuncReturnType<R (*)(Args...)>
{
    typedef R type;
};
```

Comment: `template<typename F> struct ReturnType;  template<typename R, typename... Args> struct ReturnType<R (*)(Args...)> { typedef R type; };`. Or just don't bother and use `NonVoidWrapper` for both.

Comment: `std::result_of` seems to do the job.

Comment: @T.C. the problem is that void and non void do slightly different things inside, I really have to use two different wrappers

Comment: @Lingxi can you please elaborate?

Comment: @T.C. the compilation problem was not in `ReturnType` but in `makeWrap`

Comment: @T.C. thanks, your solution works, could you post it as an answer?

Comment: @T.C. how hard is it to make the ReturnType work with lambdas (to encompass for loops of C functions for example)? I tried something like `template<>
struct ReturnType<std::function<void(void)> > {
    typedef void type;
};`  but it doesn't seem to work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no need to distinguish between `void` and other return types. For example, the following code is OK.

```
void f() {}
void g() { return f(); }
```

In general, according to [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/return):

> In a function returning `void`, the return statement with expression
>   can be used, if the expression type is `void`.

If you want to deduce the return type anyway, try using [std::result_of](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/result_of).

Comment: for `result_of` to work I need arguments to be present here `template <typename Func>
auto makeWrap(Func f)`? Or am I wrong?

Comment: To be most general, only when the argument types are provided can the return type be determined. Just consider the case when `operator()` is overloaded. How could you possibly determine the return type when no arguments are provided?

Comment: yes, I know the solution is not the most generic. Still it works for my purpose

Comment: @iggy List the cases you need to support. I will then provide an implementation in my answer.

Comment: I needed lambdas that returned void (which I have in the Notes already) It would be nice if there was a generic solution to figure out the return type of a lambda, but as you said its not possible when we don't have arguments

Comment: You can store a lambda in a `std::function` object, and then you can retrieve its return type easily.

Comment: yes, thats an option. I upvoted but can't mark it as accepted as T.C.'s answer helped the most.